# How to create numeric value restrictions in Protegé?

Tags: ontology, protege

I've got a class called music festivals. I want to make two inferred subclasses based on the ticket price of these music festivals. So I created a data property with it's domain "musicFestivals" and range is a value integer.

Now I create a new class called "betaaldFestivals" which means festivals which are paid. But lets say I want to categorise on the price. So when its higher than 30 I want to them to be paid and when its lower it should be the other class. However Im getting the same error over and over again. Second screenshot provided. I couldnt find any answers further on the internet because they the answer should be: "Muziekfestival and heeftMuziek some integer[>= 30]".

I tried making the value restriction with class expression editor (second screenshot) and the data restriction editor.

Thanks !

[image: protege screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your error message says:

> encountered integer at line 1 column 37. Expected one of Class …

That strongly suggests that you've declared **heeftMuziek** as an ObjectProperty rather than a DatatypeProperty.  If the range is an integer, then the property needs to be a DatatypeProperty, not an ObjectProperty.